# Using mutate_at to create new columns by using other columns in the same data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Okey, I'm having trouble with something that should be simple. If I have a dataframe like this:

```
x <- data.frame(a = seq(1,3), b = seq(2,4), c = seq(3,5), d = seq(4,6), b2 = seq(5,7), c2 = seq(6,8), d2 = seq(7,9))

# a b c d b2 c2 d2
# 1 2 3 4 5  6  7
# 2 3 4 5 6  7  8
# 3 4 5 6 7  8  9
```

I want to use mutate_at to create new columns based on the result from b/b2, c/c2 etc. When I try:

```
myvars <- c(2:4)
dvars <- c(5:7)
x <- x %>%
mutate_at(vars(myvars), funs('_new' = vars(myvars) / vars(dvars)))
```

I get an error "Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator."

I've also tried using `mapply` but haven't been able to make it work.
The reason I want to use mutate_at is that I want to make changes to the original columns based on the result from this division in the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly do

```
x[myvars]/x[dvars]

#          b         c         d
#1 0.4000000 0.5000000 0.5714286
#2 0.5000000 0.5714286 0.6250000
#3 0.5714286 0.6250000 0.6666667
```

---

I am not sure if you could do this with `mutate_at` however, you can use `map2_df` from `purrr`

```
purrr::map2_df(x[myvars], x[dvars], ~ .x/.y)
```

OR with `mapply`

```
mapply("/", x[myvars], x[dvars])
```

Comment: I was hoping to understand why it doesn't work with mutate_at but I guess that mapply is a better solution for a problem like this. Thanks!

Comment: @GreenManXY yes, `muatate..` applies the function on each column. Here, we have two groups of columns so it's better to use `mapply`/`map2`.

Answer (score 1):

We can make it in a expression and then evaluate with `parse_exprs` from `rlang`

```
library(dplyr)
expr1 <- paste0(names(x)[myvars], "/", names(x)[dvars])
x %>% 
     mutate(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(expr1))
```