# Using mapply to set values based on values in other columns

Tags: r, mapply

Based on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157692/using-mutate-at-to-create-new-columns-by-using-other-columns-in-the-same-data-fr/55157978?noredirect=1#comment97056524_55157978), I need help with using the `mapply` function correctly.

```
x <- data.frame(a = seq(1,3), b = seq(2,4), c = seq(3,5), d = seq(4,6), b2 = seq(5,7), c2 = seq(6,8), d2 = seq(7,9))

# a b c d b2 c2 d2
# 1 2 3 4 5  6  7
# 2 3 4 5 6  7  8
# 3 4 5 6 7  8  9
```

My goal is to look at the columns b2 to d2 and, based on their values, change the values in columns b to d respectively. I can do this for a single column quite easily:

```
x[which(x$b2 == 7),][b] <- NA_real_
```

My problem is that I want this applied across all my columns but I don't know how to convert this single column formula to work on multiple columns. I tried:

```
onez <- c(2:4)
twoz <- c(5:7)
f <- function(df, ones, twos) {
  df[which(df[,twos] == 7),][ones] <- NA_real_
}

mapply(f, df = x, ones = onez, twos = twoz)
```

But I'm getting error messages (incorrect dimensions etc) and I see that my function is messy but I lack the knowledge how to fix it.

Comment: `x[5:7][x[5:7] == 7]  <- NA`?

Comment: @Sotos Hm, that actually worked but I have no idea why. Can you explain the steps?

Comment: you mean  `x[2:4][x[5:7] == 7] <- NA` works?

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen, Yes, I forgot that I corrected it.

Comment: I added an answer. Have a look and let me know

Comment: and **change the values in columns b to d respectively** ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to tell it to:

- Get the subset of the data frame with columns 5, 6, 7: `x[5:7]`
- Check from that subset which values satisfy your condition: `x[5:7] == 7`
- Replace those values with NA: `... <- NA`

This gives the following,

```
x[5:7][x[5:7] == 7]  <- NA
x
#  a b c d b2 c2 d2
#1 1 2 3 4  5  6 NA
#2 2 3 4 5  6 NA  8
#3 3 4 5 6 NA  8  9
```

If you want the NAs to be replaced at `x[2:4]`, then you can do,

```
x[2:4][x[5:7] == 7] <- NA
x
#  a  b  c  d b2 c2 d2
#1 1  2  3 NA  5  6  7
#2 2  3 NA  5  6  7  8
#3 3 NA  5  6  7  8  9
```

Comment: It's a very simple answer, I'm just didn't realize you can subset multiple columns that way and use the subset as an index for another subset. Thanks!